# If-Statement checking vor a value between two others

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a kind of "between" check I can use in an if-statement that verifies whether a given float value is between two others?

Can I write something like

```
if (floatConstA <= checkFloatValue < foatConstB) {
```

or must I do this using AND/OR constructs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it with &&:

```
if (floatConstA <= checkFloatValue && checkFloatValue < foatConstB) {
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write it like 2 separate conditions, eg.

```
if((floatConstA <= checkFloatValue) && (checkFloatValue < floatConstB)) {
...
}
```